# How to use properties file in webserver?

Tags: java, tomcat, properties, webserver

I have a JavaSE application that makes use of a `.properties` file that is at the root of classpath.

I'm trying to convert this tool to a webserver app, which already runs fine, but the properties file is not found.

How can I make sure that this file gets copied from classpath to the webserver? How do I have to change the path of that file `new FileInputStream("file.propteries")` accordingly?

Comment: are you creating a war file to deploy inside the web server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include your properties file in the `WEB-INF/classes` directory of your war file and then use [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) passing the name of the properties file.